# Передача всего URI в cgi-скрипт с помощью mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-modules

Стандартная ситуация: есть сайт с динамически генерируемым контентом на cgi. Необходимо передать в скрипт `getpage.lua` открытый uri. Т. е. `site.com/url1/url2/url3?msg=test` в `site.com/getpage.lua?browse=url1/url2/url3&msg=test`. Однако, URI в браузере не менять.

Как такое можно сделать?
Примечание:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /getpage.lua?browse=$0 [QSA]
```

приводит к рекурсии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такое решение:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]*(?:[a-z0-9]+\.(htm|html)){0,1})$ getpage.lua?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```